# MySQL/Clickhouse combine/RANK selected results with a set label and keep the remaining unique

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I'm collecting a number of tweets over a number of days/months and are monitoring for clusters of words (hashtags). The primary db of tweets collects app 5 M tweets a day and the hashtags are extracted into a separate table. These hashtags are counted to show a heat-map that develops over the course of a period (days/months).

The collecting db is MYSQL where primary tweets table is app 500 M records and the hashtags table is app 175 M records. Then replicated to Clickhouse for analysis.

With the Coronavirus as an example, the list below show that several hashtags' could be grouped better together for improved visibility of the statistics.

**Questions:**

1. How to add a filter for selecting similar words/hashtags into one defined "tag" or alias? **DONE**
2. How to use multiple aliases, all with each set of filters/selection criterias?   **DONE**
3. How to use RANK or similar to not list using accumulated counts, but RANK?

```
SELECT (match(hashtag, '[Cc]orona.*|COVID.*|[Cc]ovid.*') ? 'COVID19' : hashtag) as Hashtag,
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 1 day AND now() then 1 END) "Today",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 2 day AND now() - interval 1 day then 1 END) "Today -1",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 3 day AND now() - interval 2 day then 1 END) "Today -2",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 4 day AND now() - interval 3 day then 1 END) "Today -3",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 5 day AND now() - interval 4 day then 1 END) "Today -4",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 6 day AND now() - interval 5 day then 1 END) "Today -5",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 7 day AND now() - interval 6 day then 1 END) "Today -6",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 8 day AND now() - interval 7 day then 1 END) "Today -7"
FROM twitterDBhashtags
group by Hashtag 
order by "Today" DESC limit 20;
```

On the **twitterDBhashtags** table:

```
id          BIGINT(20)      PK
hashtag     VARCHAR(75)
datetime    DATETIME
```

produces this result:

```
Hashtag             Today       Today -1    Today -2    Today -3    Today -4    Today -5    Today -6    Today -7
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COVID19             245 799     253 088     241 731      226 515     249 281    84 088       149 789    117 015    
BhulaDungaFirstLook 36 379       34                         
StPatricksDay       12 622       410         251         233         307         72         194         176    
BhulaDungaWithSid   12 595       47                         
QuarantineLife      10 742       2 339       59                                             1           1
UPDATE              9 432        534         1 063       340         884         215         336         242    
BREAKING            7 038        11 737      10 434      6 985       10 726      4 345       6 748       5 091    
SidNaaz             6 012        2 247       4 115       1 692       2 065       241         1 502       1 236    
China               5 840        4 803       4 887       5 472       7 039       2 086       3 392       3 748    
FamiliesFirst       4 578        420         902         6 480       5 952       1 326          
iHeartAwards        4 540        5 274       6 846       5 412       6 747       2 500       6 559       4 767    
HomeOfSoul_Satlok   4 341                               
TrumpVirus          4 094        750         752         1 381       1 935       624         590         1 176    
100WAYS             4 055        106         125         22                 
TEAMWANG            4 014        101         107         78          34          21         160         127    
ChineseVirus        3 919        1           3           4           69          32         15           2    
ShipsGoingDown      3 755        71
```

After very good input from @vladimir, using

```
SELECT case when match(hashtag, '[Cc]orona.*|COVID.*|[Cc]ovid.*') then 'COVID19' 
            when match(hashtag, 'Bhula.*') then 'Bhula'
            else hashtag END
            as Hashtag,
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 1 day AND now() then 1 END) "Today",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 2 day AND now() - interval 1 day then 1 END) "Today -1",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 3 day AND now() - interval 2 day then 1 END) "Today -2",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 4 day AND now() - interval 3 day then 1 END) "Today -3",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 5 day AND now() - interval 4 day then 1 END) "Today -4",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 6 day AND now() - interval 5 day then 1 END) "Today -5",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 7 day AND now() - interval 6 day then 1 END) "Today -6",
  SUM(CASE when datetime between now() - interval 8 day AND now() - interval 7 day then 1 END) "Today -7"
FROM twitterDBhashtags
group by Hashtag 
order by "Today" DESC limit 10;
```

I get this (please note this is live data, so SUM of results above will not be accurate)

```
Hashtag         Today   Today -1    Today -2    Today -3    Today -4    Today -5    Today -6    Today -7
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COVID19         241825  260486      237838      236318      222989      129159      161506      122959
Bhula           35267   22372       856         1           13          4           1           12
StPatricksDay   14776   1147        254         239         271         130         198         167
QuarantineLife  10442   5140        169         1                       2
AsiManshiDebut  8900                            
LuzonLockdown   6764    9                       
FamiliesFirst   6563    382         439         3285        8854        1307        927 
Italy           6516    2617        4590        4493        2710        1725        3287        8885
BREAKING        6391    9878        10726       8603        9830        4305        8464        4992
China           5469    5745        4417        5279        5753        4290        3556        3408
```

Now, how can this be made as RANK, and in stead of counts, be sorted on the RANK.

Any ideas how to progress would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define the period of date in WHERE-clause instead of listing them in SELECT:

```sql
SELECT toStartOfDay(datetime) day, match(hashtag, '[Cc]orona.*|COVID.*') ? 'COVID19' : hashtag as hashtag, count() tweets_count
FROM (
  /* test data */
  SELECT toDateTime(data.1) datetime, data.2 hashtag
  FROM (
    SELECT arrayJoin([
      ('2020-03-01 10:10:10', 'coronavirus'), 
      ('2020-03-01 12:12:12', 'COVID'), 
      ('2020-03-05 10:10:10', 'StPatricksDay'), 
      ('2020-03-15 01:01:01', 'Coronavirus')]) data)
)
WHERE datetime >= '2020-03-01 00:00:00' AND datetime < '2020-04-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY day, hashtag;

/* result
┌─────────────────day─┬─hashtag───────┬─tweets_count─┐
│ 2020-03-01 00:00:00 │ COVID19       │            2 │
│ 2020-03-15 00:00:00 │ COVID19       │            1 │
│ 2020-03-05 00:00:00 │ StPatricksDay │            1 │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┘
*/
```

---

```sql
SELECT (match(hashtag, '[Cc]orona.*|COVID.*') ? 'COVID19' : hashtag) as hashtag, sum(day1) day1, sum(day2) day2, sum(day3) day3, sum(day4) day4, sum(day5) day5, sum(day6) day6, sum(day7) day7
FROM (
  /* test data */
  SELECT data.1 AS hashtag, data.2 AS day1, data.3 AS day2, data.4 AS day3, data.5 AS day4, data.6 AS day5, data.7 AS day6, data.8 AS day7
  FROM
  (
      SELECT arrayJoin([
        ('coronavirus', 67299, 60633, 53780, 55375, 59866, 27150, 47824), 
        ('COVID', 62502, 50998, 50365, 51554, 50062, 23140, 40908), 
        ('BhulaDungaFirstLook', 35524, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        ('Coronavirus', 14076, 15297, 12321, 16496, 16263, 7028, 9975), 
        ('CoronavirusOutbreak', 13020, 9410, 2597, 1044, 1853, 950, 2436), 
        ('BhulaDungaWithSid', 12190, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        ('StPatricksDay', 10426, 374, 244, 233, 282, 79, 213), 
        ('QuarantineLife', 10110, 1477, 56, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
        ('COVID2019', 9892, 2085, 1417, 2009, 2929, 1568, 4918)]) AS data
  ))
GROUP BY hashtag;

/* result
┌─hashtag─────────────┬───day1─┬───day2─┬───day3─┬───day4─┬───day5─┬──day6─┬───day7─┐
│ COVID19             │ 166789 │ 138423 │ 120480 │ 126478 │ 130973 │ 59836 │ 106061 │
│ StPatricksDay       │  10426 │    374 │    244 │    233 │    282 │    79 │    213 │
│ QuarantineLife      │  10110 │   1477 │     56 │      0 │      1 │     0 │      0 │
│ BhulaDungaFirstLook │  35524 │     34 │      0 │      0 │      0 │     0 │      0 │
│ BhulaDungaWithSid   │  12190 │     47 │      0 │      0 │      0 │     0 │      0 │
└─────────────────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴───────┴────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Thx. What would be the benefit of using WHERE instead of listing with SELECT (I'm not a MYSQL professional)? From what I understand from your reply I would need to hardcode the data in the arrayJoin and this would very much defeat the purpose. I did try with your suggested "(match(hashtag, '[Cc]orona.*|COVID.*|[Cc]ovid.*') ? 'COVID19' : hashtag) as Hashtag " and that was very nice. How can this be extended to also add other combinations like 'COVID19' and combining other like fx 'BhulaDunga.*' as Bhula, in the same select/match?

Comment: 1. these queries specific for ClickHouse, not MySQL  2. *arrayJoin* used just for providing test-data, you shouldn't use it  3. how to extend the *match* - just look at https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/functions/string_search_functions/#match-haystack-pattern

Comment: thank you for your input, much appreciated. I unfortunately do not make much sense of the link you supplied though. The initial "match" creates an alias for the listed variants of the string. Can this be extended to a second, third.. aliases with their respective variants of strings associated with the said aliases?

Comment: it looks like you need smth like this: *select case when match(hashtag, '[Cc]orona.*|COVID.*|[Cc]ovid.*') then 'COVID19' when match(hashtag, 'he.*') then  'HELLO' else hashtag end
from (select arrayJoin(['corona1', 'Corona', 'hello', 'unknown']) hashtag);*

Comment: Yes, that seem to work :-), perfectly using ````SELECT case when match(hashtag, '[Cc]orona.*|COVID.*|[Cc]ovid.*') then 'COVID19' 
            when match(hashtag, 'Bhula.*') then 'Bhula'
            else hashtag END
            as Hashtag,```` The final question is to do a RANK on all different "Days" and list only the RANK per column.